# GitHub Jekyll Page isn't updating

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I created a page with `octopress` using `octopress new page 100-days-of-code-log` which created a `100-days-of-code-log.html`. I added an .md file of the same name. I then created a directory called `_pages` in the root of my project folder and copied those files into that directory.

I added the YAML front matter:

```
---
layout: default
title: 100 Days of Code Log
tags: [100 days of code, challenges]
modified:
permalink: "/100-Days-Of-Code-Log/"
comments: true
image:
  feature: Panorama.jpg
  credit: Divine Mayhem Photography
  creditlink: http://www.divinemayhem.com/
  ---
```

I then ran `jekyll build` and pushed the changes to GitHub.

The content on the page is not there. I added the page to `_navigation.yml` and it is in the navigation bar. However there is no content on the page.

I am using a theme by [this guy](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/) and I have followed the documentation. But the content does not appear.

Here is the code for the `page.html` for the `_layout directory`:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
{% include _head.html %}
</head>

<body class="page">

{% include _browser-upgrade.html %}

{% include _navigation.html %}

{% if page.image.feature %}
  <div class="image-wrap">
  <img src=
    {% if page.image.feature contains 'http' %}
      "{{ page.image.feature }}"
    {% else %}
      "{{ site.url }}/images/{{ page.image.feature }}"
    {% endif %}
  alt="{{ page.title }} feature image">
  {% if page.image.credit %}
    <span class="image-credit">Photo Credit: <a href="{{ page.image.creditlink }}">{{ page.image.credit }}</a></span>
  {% endif %}
  </div><!-- /.image-wrap -->
{% endif %}

<div id="main" role="main">
  <div class="article-author-side">
    {% include _author-bio.html %}
  </div>
  <article class="page">
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <div class="article-wrap">
      {{ content }}
      {% if page.share != false %}
        <hr />
        {% include _social-share.html %}
      {% endif %}
    </div><!-- /.article-wrap -->
    {% if site.owner.disqus-shortname and page.comments == true %}
      <section id="disqus_thread"></section><!-- /#disqus_thread -->
    {% endif %}
  </article>
</div><!-- /#index -->

<div class="footer-wrap">
  <footer>
    {% include _footer.html %}
  </footer>
</div><!-- /.footer-wrap -->

{% include _scripts.html %}          

</body>
</html>
```

I have looked all over the web, even here in SO and I can't seem to find the issue. I did not build this template. But I thought maybe someone who had more knowledge than I do of Jekyll could be of help.

Comment: Try doing `jekyll serve`. This will serve the files locally. Are you able to see your changes this way?

Comment: Yes, I did. There are no changes to the page.

Comment: When I open the index.html file that Jekyll generates, the content is there. Which is weird to me.

Comment: A repository url can be helpful to debug.

Comment: When a page does not have the expected content, you probably have a build error. Build errors can be viewed like this: https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-jekyll-build-error-messages/

Comment: I just deleted the page. I was having some other issues with the index.md and index.html pages I had. I think the issue was having both the html file and the md file in the same folder. I decided to delete the page and host it on another blog of mine.